# for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

How do you get every index of a vector inside a loop, this is to pass a function the values of vector

```
vector =[ 20 , 30 , 60 ,45 ,26 ,17 ,28,9, 10,3 ]


n = 10
for i=1:n
    somefunt( vector(i) );
end
```

So this is translated

```
 somefunt( vector(20) );
 somefunt( vector(30) );
 somefunt( vector(60) );
 ...
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass all the values in `vector` to your function `somefunt` in a [for loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/for.html), you can just use `vector` as your loop values like so:

```
for i = vector
  somefunt(i);
end
```

This will be equivalent to:

```
somefunt(20);
somefunt(30);
somefunt(60);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @gnovice wrote, if you want the index of the vector element you can use the `ismember` function:

```
vector =[ 20 , 30 , 60 ,45 ,26 ,17 ,28,9, 10,3 ]
for i = vector
    [TempFlag, MemberInd] = ismember( i, vector );

    fprintf('vector(%d) is %d\n', MemberInd, i);
    % somefunt( i );
end
```

Comment: If you simply need the index, you can replace the call of `ismember` for `MemberInd = find(vector==i);`